# Facebook C# SDK cannot resolve FB Login

Tags: c#, facebook, asp.net-mvc-2, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm developing an MVC-2 application with Facebook C# SDK and recently Facebook stopped to respond to my login requests. After some research, I've managed to get it working by putting 'localhost' in the 'Site Domain' field in facebook application settings.

Now, login through Facebook Javascript SDK seems to be working alright, but the Facebook C# SDK always returns the **FacebookApp.Session** value as null. To be sure that this issue is not because of some configuration or development mistakes, I've even tried the sample application from Facebook C# SDK website, but no luck.

Any suggestions on this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you building a connect site or an iframe site?

Comment: Did you start with the sample application? If you start with that it should just work out of the box. http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/releases/view/54371#DownloadId=160969

Answer (score 1):

Did you start with the sample application? If you start with that it should just work out of the box. I am guessing you have cookie support set to false in the web.config setting. http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/releases/view/54371#DownloadId=160969 Your web.config file should look like this:

```
  <configSections>
    <section name="facebookSettings" type="Facebook.FacebookConfigurationSection"/>

  </configSections>

  <facebookSettings
        apiKey="your_api_key" 
        apiSecret="your_api_secret" 
        appId="your_app_id" 
        cookieSupport="true" />
```

Also, make sure you are using the released version and not the latest source code. The source code is not for production use and has some bugs that will make it hard for you to learn the toolkit.

Comment: Unfortunately, as I told in my original post, the sample application does not work with the right settings as well. I've tried to download and run again the sample today, however it's still not functioning on my side. What else could be the reason?

Comment: That really is the only reason. Are you sure you have everything setup on facebook's side and in the config settings? I just downloaded the sample, setup and app and it ran perfectly.

Comment: worked for me. I'm using a different version of the SDK (v4.2.1) so the fields were different. i had to find them using reflector since i couldnt find it in the documentation or the sample project. For anyone else interested, in 4.2.1, they are `<facebookSettings appSecret="your_api_secret" appId="your_app_id" />`

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to work with this library, but imho wasn't that much fun.
For the Facebook Application you have to enter a static port number and your Visual Studio build in IIS have to run on this port, too.

For example:

> http://localhost:55555/

If you've got enough time, try to take a look at https://github.com/prabirshrestha/FacebookSharp. It comes with a build in FacebookController for ASP.net MVC.
Works great for me :-)

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what did you not like about the Facebook C# SDK? What does FacebookSharp do better? As far as the port, that is a Facebook security setting, and not really part of the library.